# HP ALM: Test execution results versioning

Tags: hp-alm, test-reporting

How do we create a snapshot versions of the test results of a test set in HP ALM - Test LAB

I need this versioning to keep track of the past execution details.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?  I ask because run results are always a representation of the test as it existed when it was executed.  By design, they are a historical record of your past execution details.  Perhaps if you provide a use case scenario, it will be clearer what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Here are the steps:
1. Add a test set in the test lab with some test cases. 
2. Execute the test cases and record the test results. 

I will have to re-run the same test-set for the next sprint/test-cycle, where in which I dont want to lose the existing results, Instead I need a copy of results so that I can compare the current execution result and previous execution result.

Can we do this copying of test set automatically for every sprint/test cycle minimizing the manual effort.

Comment: Can we do this copying of test set automatically for every sprint/test cycle - By taking a snapshot version of the test set. (or any other way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you need to copy/archive/version anything to get the results you need.  Consider this...

## First Testing Effort

Follow these steps for the first time you are executing tests.

1. Create your test set
2. Add the tests that will be part of your effort.
3. All tests will be in the "No Run" status with no run history
4. Execute your tests (multiple times as necessary if they do not pass initially) until your effort is complete.

## Second Testing Effort

The next time you need to run the tests, use the same test set.

1. Reset the test set.  Right-click the test set in Test Lab and select 'Reset Test Set'.  This step will reset the 'Status of all your previous test runs to 'No Run'.
2. Execute your tests (multiple times as necessary if they do not pass initially) until your effort is complete.

## Comparison

At this time, each test has maintained a full run history.  All the runs from the First Effort are still available along with those from the Second Effort.  Open the Test Instance details of one of the tests in your test set, and then select the 'Runs' option.  There you will be able to see each and every time that test instance was executed, no matter which testing effort it was.

## Alternative

If this doesn't meet your needs, an alternative would be to leave the test set from your first testing effort alone when you are done.  When your second effort beings, copy/paste your test set and perform all your new runs from that copy.  When you copy/paste, it does not copy run history, so the new test set will be a blank slate.  There is a COM-based API for doing all of this through code if necessary.

Comment: Thats perfect. Thanks for all the info. A bit curious to know more about the COM-Based API. Any details of that will really help. :)

Comment: HP refers to their API as "Open Test Architecture" or "OTA".  If you check the Help documentation with Quality Center/ALM, you'll see a detailed help guide along with many code examples based on VBScript (but you can use any language that supports COM).  There is also a REST API available, but it does not provide as much functionality.  I'm not certain it would support copying a test set.